# list used symbols of a certain dynamically loaded library

Tags: c, linker, dependencies, symbols

I'd like to list the symbols a program loads from a specific library. You can list the needed libraries with ldd:

```
    ldd -v myExecutable
```

This gives something like the following output:

```
    libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.11) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Now I'd like to know which symbols are loaded from which library. Specifically, in my case I'd like to find those that are loaded from GLIBC_2.11 and eventually get rid of them.

(I'm already using [ligcc](http://listaller.tenstral.net/wiki/doku.php/ligcc) to avoid linking against new symbols - now I'd like to see which symbols are not available before 2.11)

Comment: Try `nm /path/to/libc.so`. Beware though - it will be quite a long list you might want to pipe it to `less`.

Comment: I don't want to list the symbols of a library, I want to know which are used by an executable. Thought that was clear from the question!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nm` might satisfy what you're after. Just used it on my executable, and it does  give versions of the library along with the symbol. eg:

```
U tan@@GLIBC_2.0
```

so you could do a grep to find only the version you're interested in.

Comment: I first misread this answer, being similar to Linuxios comment, but actually, `nm myExec | grep GLIBC_2.11` works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Use `LD_DEBUG` environment variable. E.g.:

```
$ LD_USE_LOAD_BIAS=0 LD_DEBUG=all ls |& grep binding
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_res' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_IO_file_close' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `stderr' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `error_one_per_line' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__malloc_initialize_hook' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]: normal symbol `_dl_starting_up' [GLIBC_PRIVATE]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__morecore' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__key_encryptsession_pk_LOCAL' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__progname_full' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__ctype32_tolower' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_environ' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]: normal symbol `_rtld_global' [GLIBC_PRIVATE]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__progname' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `argp_err_exit_status' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `mallwatch' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__rcmd_errstr' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `svcauthdes_stats' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file /lib64/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]: normal symbol `__libc_enable_secure' [GLIBC_PRIVATE]
 [...]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__libc_start_main' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `strrchr' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `setlocale' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `bindtextdomain' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `textdomain' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__cxa_atexit' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `isatty' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `getenv' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__ctype_b_loc' [GLIBC_2.3]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__errno_location' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `strtoul' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `ioctl' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `getopt_long' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `malloc' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `memcpy' [GLIBC_2.14]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `strlen' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `opendir' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `readdir' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `closedir' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `free' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_setjmp' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `strcoll' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__ctype_get_mb_cur_max' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `fwrite_unlocked' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `exit' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__fpending' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `fileno' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__freading' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `fflush' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 22160: binding file ls [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `fclose' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
```

For more details see `man ld.so`.

Comment: This looks promising, although the output seems to disagree with ldd: `LD_DEBUG=all myExec |& grep GLIBC_2.11` gives no result, but ldd says it is needed. (I do get results for other Versions)

Comment: @DanielS The output is incomplete because it was prelinked with `prelink`. `LD_USE_LOAD_BIAS=0` disables prelinking and allows to see all the bindings. I updated the answer.

Comment: Your answer surely shows deep insight, however, even the updated answer does not print a GLIBC_2.11 dependency. J20's answer does what I want and i found that **execvpe@@GLIBC_2.11** is the disturbing symbol - so I grep'ed for 'exec' in your output and it gave me `execvp [GLIBC_2.2.5]` and `execv [GLIBC_2.2.5]` (and not execvpe, which I used) - could it be that execvpe uses those internally and inlined it, therefore not actually called, but still left as a dependency?

Comment: Can't add anything about `execvpe`. On Fedora 17 it is not an inline function, so I would expect it to show up in `ld.so` output. Anyway, I'd say `nm` and `LD_DEBUG` are two complimentary rather than exclusive methods.